# How to fix this error - Not Found: /firstapp/ "GET /firstapp/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2065"

Tags: django

I have created a project named firstproject and added a new project firstapp in which urls.py of firstapp is invoked to call view.py which displays a string in webpage. But the webpage is showing error.

I have created a project named firstproject and added a new project firstapp in which urls.py of firstapp is invoked to call view.py which displays a string in webpage. But the webpage is showing error.

firstapp

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns={
    url('r^$',views.index,name='index')
}
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<H2> Hey Everyone welcome to Django Tutorial! </H2>")

# Create your views here.
```

firstproject

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$/', include('firstapp.urls')),
]
```

I expect the output to be "Hey Everyone welcome to Django Tutorial!"

Comment: You have quite a few mistakes here in your URLs. But where do you think you've defined the path `/firstapp/`?

Comment: can you show project directory structure

Comment: have you added firstapp in installed_app in settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your firstapp urls.py there is a mistake use [] instead of {}

second mistake in is your code url regex **('r^$')** is wrong

change it to **(r'^$')**

in firstapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
  url(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
]
```

Comment: Well that's *one* of the issues, but not one that is causing the problem OP is having.